# what is the meaning of $\frac{F[x]}{(f(x))}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, notation, field-theory

There is a theorem in algebra which says: *"let $F$ be a field and assume $f(x) \in F[x]$ is irreducible, then $\frac{F[x]}{(f(x))}$ is a field"*.

I have the proof of this theorem, but I can't get the meaning of $\frac{F[x]}{(f(x))}$. I don't know what does it really mean, so, although the proof of this theorem seems very easy, I can't get it.

I would really appreciate it if someone helped me understand the meaning of this fraction!

Comment: It is a [quotient ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring).

Comment: I don't know if this could be helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253187, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1145015, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1826188

Answer (score 1):

First you have to get the meaning of the *quotient ring* $R/I$ of a ring $R$ by an ideal $I$. Then one can take $R$ as the polynomial ring $F[x]$ over a field $F$ and $I$ the ideal generated by a polynomial $f\in F[x]$. Then $R/I=F[x]/(f(x))$. The Theorem you mentioned has been proved in [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272784/let-f-be-a-field-fx-is-a-polynomial-in-fx-e-fx-f-is-a-field).
The next task is to study some simple examples, e.g.,
$$
\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1),\; \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+3,p)
$$
see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1145015/how-to-compute-the-elements-of-the-field-mathbbrx-langle-x21-rangle), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1586458/determining-the-structure-of-the-quotient-ring-mathbbzx-x23-p).